# Code to read from excel sheet is not working

Tags: java, selenium, excellibrary

I have the following code to read from a test file and print it on console but it's not printing any thing, I don't know how to chech the error its generating. I am using java, selenium, ie 10, win 8.

```
public class Rowcount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException {
        FileInputStream exo=new FileInputStream("E:\\Test filee.xlsx");
        Workbook wbo=Workbook.getWorkbook(exo);
        Sheet wso=wbo.getSheet(0);
        int lastrownum;
        lastrownum= wso.getRows();
        System.out.println(lastrownum);
    }
}
```

Comment: ""E:\\Test filee.xlsx"" quotes twice... Is it compiling??. Are you getting any exception??

Comment: Sure that is correct? ""E:\\Test filee.xlsx""

Comment: sorry, i edited this one in code before compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code worked for me:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

public class ReadExcell {
public static void main(String[] args) {
ReadExcell.ExcelFile("D:\\rptViewer.xls");
}

/*
* Read excel file using j excel file
*/
public static String ExcelFile(String path){
StringBuilder excelContent = new StringBuilder();

try
{
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(path));
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

excelContent = new StringBuffer();

for(int rows = 0 ; rows < sheet.getRows() ; rows++){
StringBuffer row = new StringBuffer();
for(int colums = 0 ; colums < sheet.getColumns() ;colums++){
  Cell cell = sheet.getCell(colums, rows);
if(cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL){
row.append(cell.getContents()+ ",");
}else
if(cell.getType() == CellType.NUMBER){
row.append(cell.getContents()+ ",");
}
}

excelContent.append(row.toString());
System.out.println(row.toString());
}

} catch (BiffException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}    

return excelContent.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JExcelApi? If so, I don't think it supports Excel 2007 and above. You might consider looking into [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 1):

jxl didnt work for xlsx. try to implement using apache poi instead

and this code is misquoted

```
FileInputStream exo=new FileInputStream(""E:\\Test filee.xlsx"");
```

you would need to remove the extra quote